# How to get user by email in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a form that collects users email addresses and I would like to be able to get their name, profile picture. Is there a method that allows me to get a user by email address?

Comment: Welcome. You ask a question that appears to demand a yes/no answer. But to answer there is a lot of information that you have ignored or omitted. Is this Google Forms, where would one collect their names and profiles? What code have you already written? what research have you already done. Please re-read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then **edit your question to provide more and relevant information about your question and your problem**.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scope. Is it an internal Google Form and are the users within your G Suite environment? In this case you can lookup the user in the AdminDirectory.

`var userInfo = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email);`

If the users are not in your G Suite environment users needs to allow you to read their profile info. It's not possible to arrange this by a Google Form.